# Using an equation as a constraint and building a constraint matrix

Tags: optimization, conic-sections, least-squares, point-cloud

Given a list of points $(x_1, x_2) \in \Bbb R^2$, I would like to find the ellipse that best fits the given points in the least-squares sense. I have a general function $f :\Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ of the form

$$f({\bf a}, {\bf x}) = a_0 x_1^2 + a_1 x_1 x_2 + a_2 x_2^2 + a_3 x_1 + a_4 x_2 + a_5 = {\bf a}^\top {\bf x}$$

**a** = ($_0$ $_1$ $_2$ $_3$ $_4$ $_5)^T$, **x** = ($x_1^2$ $x_1x_2$ $x_2^2$ $x_1$ $x_2$ 1)$^T$.

One of the steps is as follows. Use the equation $4_0_2 − _1^2$ = 1 as constrain and build constrain matrix $C$ so that $a^T C a = 1$.

I don't understand how to build matrix $C$. I am pretty confident it has to be a matrix of numbers. Here is the full article I use:

- M P Lawiyuniarti, E Rahmadiantri, I M Alamsyah, G Rachmaputri, [Application of least-squares fitting of ellipse and hyperbola for two dimensional data](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1742-6596/948/1/012069)  [[PDF]](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/948/1/012069/pdf), 2018.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo x and a are vectors, although they can be called matrices too. And yes, I need to find the best ellipse using given points (they have some errors, this is why I use least squares method)

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47873759)

Comment: I improved a bit. Please improve the rest. You are copying from somewhere else and your symbols are all messed up. Please fix that.

Comment: Have you tried googling `fit ellipse to points site:math.stackexchange.com`?

Comment: The authors' choice of notation is horrible. You don't have to suffer due to their choices.

Answer (score 1):

The constraint matrix $C$ is as follows

$C = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 && 2 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 
0 && -1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
2 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 &&0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $